# Laravel API '401 Unauthorized'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api

Estoy realizando un login desde VUE hacia mi API de Laravel para acceder a los datos de un usuario tras el login con la siguiente petición:

```
  mounted() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user').then((response) => {
      this.user = response.data})
  }
```

Pero en el navegador obtengo este error:

> Status Code: 401 Unauthorized

Junto con este mensaje:

> {message: "Unauthenticated."} message: "Unauthenticated."

La ruta a la que se realiza la petición es la siguiente:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Alguna idea de como poder mostrar la información del usuario que ha realizado el login?

**EDIT**

He añadido el siguiente código a la petición que realizo para el login, según la documentación.

```
  axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
      console.log(response)
  });
```

Esta petición previa al login no me da ningun error,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que persiste es el 401 a la hora de mostrar la información del usuario.

Comment: Está en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#csrf-protection

Comment: Donde debería incluir esta petición?

Comment: Si es una SPA, debes hacer esa petición para autenticar las peticiones subsecuentes.

Comment: He añadido esto y luego he realizado el login, pero al intentar mostrar la información del usuario sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: Como ya te mencionaron, está explicado en la documentación. Edita la pregunta con un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable de tu código donde muestres cómo aplicas esos pasos que están en la documentación de laravel

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ hecho

Comment: Bueno, pero te faltan pasos... Primero asegurate de tener configurados los [cors y cookies](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#cors-and-cookies), luego pides la cookie y al tenerla, haces el login `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(() => { // login }; });`, finalmente haces la llamada a un endpoint protegido